# plot plotly bar plot for different sorted values

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, bar-chart

I have a table of names which are nodes in a graph and their respective degree and connectivity. I put them in a dataframe called stat_df:

```
0   node                                            degree      connectivity
1   Antonio da Correggio                            0.142857    0.5
2   Adriaen van der Werff                           0.011905    0.4
3   Agnolo Gaddi                                    0.000000    0.3
4   Filippino Lippi                                 0.071429    0.1
```

I want to use go.Bar to plot the top five of each property (degree, connectivity) in one bar, so one bar to degree, one bar to connectivity and with different colors for each node name in each bar.
the following code kind of works (without the different colors) when the ascending property of srot_values is True, but won't work when it is false. and even if i kept it true and changed .head() to .tail() it won't work.

```
data = [go.Bar(x = [x for x in stat_df.sort_values('Degree', ascending=False)['Degree'].head(5)],  
               y = [x for x in stat_df.sort_values('Degree', ascending=False)['node'].head(5)], orientation='h', name= 'Degree'), 
        go.Bar(x = [x for x in stat_df.sort_values('Connectivity', ascending=False)['Connectivity'].head(5)],  
               y = [x for x in stat_df.sort_values('Connectivity', ascending=False)['node'].head(5)], orientation='h', name = 'Connectivity')]

fig = go.Figure(data,)
```

Any help is appreciate it.
Thanks

Comment: I ran the code in your question and it graphed correctly. I am not sure I understand your issue.

Comment: It doesn't work as I wanted using the above code. The bars were next to each other instead on top of each other. The code i supplied below works much better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was bale to do it by changing the stat_df so the degree and connectivity (which i should called betweenness instead) appended on top of each other instead. here is the code:

```
def Stats(G):
        degree = nx.degree_centrality(G)
        betweenness = nx.betweenness_centrality(G)
        degree_df = pd.DataFrame({'node': [x[0] for x in sorted(degree.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)] , 'Stat':'Degree', 'Value': [x[1] for x in sorted(degree.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)]})
        betweenness_df = pd.DataFrame({'node': [x[0] for x in sorted(betweenness.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)] , 'Stat':'betweenness', 'Value': [x[1] for x in sorted(betweenness.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)]})
        bar_df = degree_df.head(5).append(betweenness_df.head(5))[['node', 'Stat', 'Value']]
        
        data = px.bar(bar_df, x="Stat", y="Value", color="node", title="Top five stat", orientation='v')
        layout = go.Layout(title = "General Stats", 
                                template = 'plotly_dark', 
                                paper_bgcolor ='rgba(0,0,0,0)', plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                                xaxis = go.XAxis(title = 'Dieharder Tests', showticklabels=False),)
        fig = go.Figure(data, layout)

        return fig
```

Thanks